# LDAP URL in .Net Framework

Tags: .net, url, ldap

how I get CLR file from lDAP server in C# App?
same code in java is this:
// create LDAP URL

```
String urlStr =  "ldap://ldap.signatur.rtr.at/CN=Telekom-Control-"+
  "Kommission%20Top%201,O=Telekom-Control-Kommission,"+
  "C=AT?caCertificate;binary";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
// open connection
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
// get a stream and read the certificate
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate(is);
```

Answer (score 1):

Break the URL into two parts, the LDAP path and the target attribute.

Path: `ldap://ldap.signatur.rtr.at/CN=Telekom-Kommission%20Top%201,O=Telekom-Control-Kommission,C=AT`

Attribute: `caCertificate`

Then, making ldap:// uppercase and taking out the HTML escaping, get the binary certificate:

```
using System.DirectoryServices;

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.signatur.rtr.at/" + 
  "CN=Telekom-Kommission Top 1,O=Telekom-Control-Kommission,C=AT");
byte[] binaryCertificate = (byte[])de.Properties["caCertificate"].Value;
```